# Click a WPF button that's visible on mouse hover

Tags: c#, wpf

The Button here is only visible when the mouse id hovered over the page. i am trying to test(Click) the button through my code and its failing. I have tried options like hovering and then clicking, but doesn't work either.
For information :
This button is placed inside a StackPanel (say A), which has the same property as the button (visible only after mouse hover). This A Grid is again embedded inside Grid B, which is visible.

Xaml:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="CenterButtons" Margin="10,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}" >
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=CenterButtons, Path=(Grid.Row)}" Value="0">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=CenterButtons, Path=(Grid.Row)}" Value="1">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Style>
                    <Button Name="DeletePageButton" Command="{Binding MarkForDeletionCommand}" Style="{StaticResource NoBorderVectorButtonStyle}"
                                ToolTip="{x:Static resx:DocPdfPages.ToolTipMarkForDeletion}"
                                controls:AdditionalAttachedProperties.GeometryData="{DynamicResource DeleteGlyph}"/>
                    <Button Name="RotateCounterClockwiseButton" Command="{Binding RotateLeftCommand}"
                            Style="{StaticResource NoBorderVectorButtonStyle}"
                            ToolTip="{x:Static resx:DocPdfPages.ToolTipRotatePageLeft}"
                            controls:AdditionalAttachedProperties.GeometryData="{DynamicResource RotateGlyph}">
                        <Button.LayoutTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1" />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Button.LayoutTransform>
                    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Why do you need to test click it? One of the good reasons to use `Command`s on buttons is so you can invoke the command without UI interaction.

Comment: Ok. I get it, but can you help me how do I do that. new to this so I suck :(

Comment: No worries, let me post an answer real fast.

Comment: I have a sneaky suspicion that it's the geometry data that is messing up the content presenter, I used a geaometry data for button and I had to click directly on the geometry to invoke either event handler or a command. Remove the geometry and try if clicking works then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the benefits to using a `Command` instead of a Click handler is that you can manually invoke the `Command` from code, without requiring UI interaction. This is helpful for testing scenarios such as yours.

You will find the `Command`s on whatever your `DataContext` is for this. You can then invoke it like this:

```
        ICommand deletionCommand = DataContext.MarkForDeletionCommand;
        if (deletionCommand.CanExecute(null))
            deletionCommand.Execute(null);
```

Your commands do not take any parameters, so you should get the correct behavior by giving it `null` for the parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure what your DataContext is for the Button, but whatever the DataContext of your Button is (a ViewModel, the containing Control, etc.) is where you'll find the Commands

Comment: I do get your point, but I have another question. This might be alittle dumb though. The Xaml file is in its own place. and i am writing this test case in another file (though both are completely referable to each other). Now how do I use the DataContext from the Xaml file to invoke the command on the button (which need to be wriiten in the test.cs file )

Comment: DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Grid}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=DataContext}

Comment: Not a bad question, hard to answer exactly without seeing everything but I'll give it a shot: The DataContext for your control is the *source* of your bindings, so if you succesfully bind a Button.Command to `MarkForDeleteCommand` as you have, wherever you find that command is your current DataContext (cont.)

Comment: With what you've pasted, your DataContext is bound to theDataContext of the containing Grid, so you have to find out what that is. It may be a ViewModel, or bound to *another* DataContext, but you have to work your way to the actual DataContext object. It is generally a ViewModel on the entire containing control, or the control itself.

Try something like this: Make an instance of your control, then see if you can access the command via `MyControl.DataContext.MarkForDeletionCommand`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126264/discussion-between-reema-and-geef).